# OS Type Conflict running Azure CLI command from PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli, azure-vm

I am running an Azure CLI command in a Windows 10 Professional PowerShell script and I receive this error:

```
(Conflict) Run command OS type 'Windows' does not match the target OS Linux.
```

PowerShell version:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      19041  1237
```

The failing PowerShell script:

```
$ResourceGroup= "Development"
$VmName = "ubuntu-test"

 az vm run-command invoke `
--resource-group $ResourceGroup `
--name $VmName `
--command-id RunPowerShellScript `
--scripts "ufw disable"
```

Note: The ` character is the backtick. The one on the same key as the tilde ~

The same command without line continuation backticks works:

```
az vm run-command invoke --resource-group Development --name ubuntu-test --command-id RunShellScript --scripts "ufw disable"
```

If I do a Write-Host the output is a single line with the correct arguments minus the quotes around the --script command.

```
Write-Host az vm run-command invoke `
--resource-group $ResourceGroup `
--name $VmName `
--command-id RunPowerShellScript `
--scripts "ufw disable"

az vm run-command invoke --resource-group Development --name ubuntu-test --command-id RunPowerShellScript --scripts ufw disable
```

The documentation for the AZ CLI invoke command mentions nothing about setting the OS Type.

[az VM run-command invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_run_command_invoke)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the use of line-continuations (`` ` `` at the very end of lines) is *incidental* to your problem.

Apart from the use of variables vs. literals, **the crucial difference between your multi-line command and your working single-line command is:

`--command-id RunPowerShellScript` vs. `--command-id RunShellScript`**.

It looks like **the VM you're targeting is a *Linux* machine**, and that **`--command-id RunPowerShellScript` isn't supported there**, whereas `--command-id RunShellScript` is.

[`az vm run-command list ...`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/run-command?view=azure-cli-latest#az_vm_run_command_list) can apparently be used to discover supported `--command-id` values.

Comment: Thank you. This is an example of **not seeing** a problem right in front of me. Even in my question is used two different forms **RunShellScript** and **RunPowerShellScript**. Your second eyes solved my problem. Now I also know why the error message said Windows. I knew that PowerShell run commands are not supported on Linux.